# Identity server 4 loclaAPi Frequently giving Error: Response status code does not indicate success: 503 (Server has been shutdown)

Tags: asp.net-core-mvc, identityserver4

I am using identity server 4 for token base authentication i have a asp.net mvc core application which is using code flow to get access token and i id token. I am using identity model client to get code and then access token and idtoken from identity server 4. Now when i get access token and i tries to hit localapi which is in identity server 4, first time it gives me this error "Response status code does not indicate success: 503 (Server has been shutdown)". And when i hit second time and hits again and again it does not give that error anymore.

Comment: So do you confirm the identity server4 server status and show us related configuration codes

Comment: yes i did confirm identity server is running all the time when i got this error